# Change color for every second ul li with a "for loop"

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript in codecademy and so far I understand how alot of things work. Sadly they dont explain how to target an elements color or how to target elements / selectors / divs.

I am testing out my knowledge. What I am trying is to give every second list item the color red by using the for loop.

How do I do this?

```
var listColor = function(){
    var color = style.("red");
    var list = getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i + 2;) {
    list === color   
    }
    ];
    listColor();
```

and here my http://jsfiddle.net/Lr8nZ/15/

UPDATED JSfiddle but still not working http://jsfiddle.net/Lr8nZ/23/

so basically:

Red,
Black,
Red,
Black

Comment: you can do that in CSS using :nth-child(odd), no need for JS.

Comment: @dandavis im fully aware as I used it often but im studying for loops which is why im trying to see how this is done

Comment: in that case, "i+=2" instead of "i + 2" is all you really need to change, or you can make it complicated with modulo and conditionals and twice as much iteration as needed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few syntax errors, but you can do this:

```
var listColor = function() {
  var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

  for (var i = 0, l = list.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      list[i].style.color = 'red';
    }
  }
};

// Or...

var listColor = function() {
  var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

  for (var i = 0, l = list.length; i < l; i += 2) {
    list[i + 1].style.color = 'red';
  }
};

listColor();
```

When you increment `i` make sure you're updating its value with `i++` or `i += 1`, or you'll create an endless loop.

`i % 2` uses the `%` modulus operator. It's the remainder you would get from dividing the two numbers. Even numbers divide evenly by 2, so the remainder will be 0, which we check for.

The property you were looking for is called `style`. It has a property called `color` which we set to the string `'red'` in this case.

Comment: Just one thing, why do we add the a modulus here? I dont understand that part. I know what the modulus does but why is it useful here?

Comment: When you divide an even number by 2, you won't have a remainder, so it'll be 0. If you divide an odd number by 2, you'll have a remainder of 1. So, we can check that the remainder was 0 to ensure we have an even number.

Comment: @jfairbank im asking because this is what I have done before http://jsfiddle.net/LHGdn/28/

Comment: @dandavis check out my other jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LHGdn/28/ here I didnt use an if. Thats why I was just wondering

Comment: No, you would have to increment by 2 like dandavis suggested. In that case you would remove the conditional and increment by i += 2. I'll update the code to show that.

Comment: @jfairbank Check this out, I improved your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lr8nZ/27/  eventhough the if works I wanted to try a different method to0 and it works :D

Comment: Nice, I had just added that to my example, but it looks like you got it ;)

Comment: Im still new to Javascript jfairbank and im really happy you showed me the right direction. How long do you think till I nailed it? I started since yesterday and dont have any programming experience so I hope to be able to learn this language :(

Comment: It all takes time. We've all been there; I started with JavaScript too. Give it a few weeks, and I'm sure you'll be on the right track to understanding it better. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Something do like this.

```
  var listColor = function(){

  var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if(i%2==0)
    list[i].style="color:red";
    else
        list[i].style="color:blue";

   }
 }
 listColor();
```

Comment: I know there are better ways like css3 but I want to do it regardless since im learning javascript.  check out my new jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/Lr8nZ/23/

Comment: I tried your example but it didnt work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">



    $(document).ready(function(){
        index=1;    
        $("#temp li").each(function(){
            if(index%2==0)
            {
                $(this).css("color","red")
            }
            index++;
        });
    })

    </script>
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body>

<ul id='temp'>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a console to see the errors in your code. It's a tool that's indispensible for any js coder. Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lr8nZ/24/

The first thing which you notice is `style.color('red')`. For this line to be even valid js, there has to be a style object defined. Otherwise it will search for it on `window` which always leads to confusion.

Another thing is note how we have to actually assign the new value to `i` in for loop' third condition. Just mentioning `i+2` will not work because `i` will stay the same resulting in an infinite loop.

Again, fire up web console. Generally, you do that by right clicking on page > Inspect > Web console.